# .fail() fails to execute when ajax request is not successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a random quote machine (learning AJAX). AJAX request works and .done() successfully called. Now I am trying to do error handling and my .fail() does not work when AJAX request actually is not successful. 
Any ideas what might be wrong here? Thank you!
        `

```
var quoteRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        if ($.isEmptyObject(backupQuote)){
         $quoteText.text('Failed to get a new quote');
         $author.text('');
        }
        else {
        $quoteFail.text('Failed to get a new quote');
        $quoteText.text(backupQuote.quoteText);
        $author.text(backupQuote.quoteAuthor);
        };
        }, 8000);


   $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/",
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            method: "getQuote",
            lang: "en",
            format: "jsonp"
        },
        cache: false
    })
   .done(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        $quoteText.text(data.quoteText);
        $author.text(data.quoteAuthor);
        backupQuote = {
            quoteText: data.quoteText,
            quoteAuthor: data.quoteAuthor
        };
        $quoteFail.text('');
        clearTimeout(quoteRequestTimeout);
     })
   .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown.toString());
        console.log("it worked");
     });`
```

Comment: With jsonp requests, it isn't guaranteed that the error callback will be called.

Comment: The documentation states *"This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests"*

Comment: But look at this right here - https://jsfiddle.net/3br9j365/1/ it does show my message "it worked"

Comment: Yes, it does work under some circumstances.  To be clear though, that fiddle doesn't go to the error callback.